# Function in Python giving weird set of errors, yet outputs the correct answer

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a function in Python that takes a list of lists of numbers and prints the averages on each line. But when I do so, it prints the answers, then gives an error block that I cannot find information about on the python documentation website.

```
def avg(lst):

    """lst is a list that contains lists of numbers; the
    function prints, one per line, the average of each list"""

    count = 0
    while count<=(len(lst)):
        print(sum(lst[count])/(len(lst[count])))
        count = count + 1
```

When this is run with lst [[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]] , it yields an output of:

```
>>> avg([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])
90.0
60.0
87.0
11.0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#38>", line 1, in <module>
    avg([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])
  File "<pyshell#37>", line 7, in avg
    print(sum(lst[count])/(len(lst[count])))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The answers are right, but I'm not sure why there's that error. Any ideas?

EDIT: changed while count<(len(lst)+1): to while count<=(len(lst)): Still yields same error

Comment: I changed that line to while count<=(len(lst)): and it still gives the same set of errors

Comment: `count<=(len(lst))` is the same as `count<(len(lst)+1)`

Comment: `count<=(len(list))` is the same thing as `count<(len(lst)+1)`. Try `count < len(lst)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have this:

```
while count<(len(lst)+1):
```

You're going past the end of the list.

Your loop does an iteration for each item in the list (giving you the correct output), and then does one more, causing the error.

Get rid of the `+1`.

Comment: I changed that line to while count<=(len(lst)): and it still gives the same set of errors

Comment: `count<=(len(lst))` is the same as `count<(len(lst)+1)`. Use `count < len(lst)`.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a for loop instead of the while loop; in addition to removing the opportunity for a fencepost error, the code is just easier to read (IMO):

```
def avg(lst):
    for l in lst: print(sum(l) / len(l))
avg([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the functionality you are looking for by defining your function as:

```
mean = lambda x: sum(x) / float(len(x))
avg = lambda x: map(mean, x)
```

Test it as:

```
>>> avg([[95, 92, 86, 87], [66, 54], [89, 72, 100], [33, 0, 0]])
[90.0, 60.0, 87.0, 11.0]
```

The index out of bounds error occurs due to an off-by-one error in line `while count<(len(lst)+1):`. The condition should probably be `while count<(len(lst)):`.

Comment: lookitchoo, with the lambda! :)